# How do I choose a random textContent?

Tags: javascript, button, random

Edit:  my Js fiddle link didn't attach, trying again:  https://jsfiddle.net/jbLd3kt1/

I am trying to make a simple generator with Javascript just for fun. It's an outfit generator with different combinations of clothing.

Right now I have two buttons for two types of outfits. Type A is a sweater, long sleeved shirt, and pants. Type B is an overshirt, long sleeved shirt, and pants.  I want to instead have one button, and it will randomly select an outfit type (#falloutfita or #falloutfitb) and then generate the random outfit based on that.

I thought maybe I could use an "or" || with the textContent but it looks like it's not possible.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var allsweaters = ["blue hoodie", "black hoodie", "pink v-neck sweater", "gray pullover"];
var allpants = ["black casual pants", "dark old navy jeans", "medium old navy jeans", "black jumpsuit"];
var alllongshirts = ["long-sleeved white shirt", "long-sleeved gray shirt", "long-sleeved black shirt"];
var allovershirts = ["white button-up", "green jacket", "blue jean shirt"];

document.querySelector("#submitfalla").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var sweater = "";
  var pants = "";
  var lsshirt = "";
  var random_index = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < 1;i++){
    random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allsweaters.length - 1));
      sweater += allsweaters[random_index];
    random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allpants.length - 1));
      pants += allpants[random_index];
    random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allpants.length - 1));
      lsshirt += alllongshirts[random_index];
  }

  document.querySelector("#falloutfita").textContent = sweater + " and " + lsshirt + " and " + pants;
});
  document.querySelector("#submitfallb").addEventListener("click", () => {
    var overshirt = "";
    var pants = "";
    var lsshirt = "";
    var random_index = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 1;i++){
      random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allovershirts.length - 1));
        overshirt += allovershirts[random_index];
      random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allpants.length - 1));
        pants += allpants[random_index];
      random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allpants.length - 1));
        lsshirt += alllongshirts[random_index];
    }


  document.querySelector("#falloutfitb").textContent = overshirt + " and " + lsshirt + " and " + pants;

});
```

It's my first post on stack overflow, please let me know if there is any way I should edit this question too!  I've looked at similar questions here but haven't been able to successfully apply them to mine.

Comment: Yup `Math.floor(Math.random() * (allsweaters.length -1))` et all

Comment: Kinglish is right! Could you post it on the answer form for the questioner?

Comment: @isherwood Thank you.  I've added more of my code and rephrased the question to hopefully clear it up!

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about that?

```
const allSweaters   = ['blue hoodie', 'black hoodie', 'pink v-neck sweater', 'gray pullover']
const allPants      = ['black casual pants', 'dark old navy jeans', 'medium old navy jeans', 'black jumpsuit']
const allLongShirts = ['long-sleeved white shirt', 'long-sleeved gray shirt', 'long-sleeved black shirt']
const allOverShirts = ['white button-up', 'green jacket', 'blue jean shirt']

function getRandomlyFrom (array) {
  return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))]
}

function getRandomOutfit () {
  return [
    getRandomlyFrom(allSweaters),
    getRandomlyFrom(allPants),
    getRandomlyFrom(
      getRandomlyFrom([allLongShirts, allOverShirts]) // return one of the two arrays
    )
  ].join(' and ')
}

function onClick () {
  document.querySelector('#falloutfita').textContent = getRandomOutfit()
}

document.querySelector('#submitfalla').addEventListener(onClick)
```